# Пункты меню в Joomla

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, cms

Пункты меню не реагируют на нажатие левого стика мыши. На нажатие колёсика мышки - переходит на страницу , на левый стик - нет. Помогите, в чем может быть проблема? В шаблоне были переходи по якорям, хотел поменять на переход по ссылке и что-т не работает

Comment: По всей вероятности в где то в JS файле установлен запрет (preventDefault() ) на нажатие ссылок в данном меню. Надо найти JS/JQuery код и удалить/закомментировать

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло)

Comment: Уважаемые участники, дайте ответ на этот вопрос и примите его, иначе потом Дух Сообщества поднимет данный вопрос за неимением ответов вообще и принятого ответа в частности. Это засоряет ленту. Спасибо.

Comment: @DaemonHK принять ответ может только автор вопроса. Скопировать ответ из комментариев - любой участник, включая вас. Не обязательно для этого звать модераторов :)

Comment: @PashaPash я понимаю это)) Но, 1 - это не честно по отношению к участникам вопроса, 2 - автор может забить просто и не принять ответ, ибо уже получил его в комментариях, а потом Дух естественно через полгода поднимет данный вопрос в топ. В общем, старая песня о главном))

Comment: @DaemonHK ну так в чем проблема?  Возьмите и скопируйте ответ из комментария.  Дух не поднимает вопросы если на ответах есть голоса за.  Модераторы все равно не могут принять ответ за автора.  Не надо их звать. Единственная разница - репутацию за скопированный ответ получил модератор,  а не вы

Comment: @PashaPash да черт с ней, репутацией)) хорошо, буду иметь в виду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Найди, где делается `preventDefault` и удали его.